# CocoaMQTT iOS client cannot connect to a broker with TLS

Tags: swift, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2

CocoaMQTT client is running on iOS15 with the SSL enabled as shown in this [example](https://github.com/emqx/CocoaMQTT/blob/4ef7bdcf3f0a754790dab8bff86dec67a695ee3c/Example/Example/ViewController.swift#L67). The cert_key.p12 file was merged from the client.crt and client.key files signed by the same (self-created) CA that was used for the MQTT server/broker certificate generation. The MQTT broker is configured to require client's certificate and use its CN as the username. The handshake does not go well - the log complains about the unknown certificate:

```
New connection from 192.168.1.87 on port 8883.
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown
```

Based on the above error research, the broker does not like the client's certificate, right? In fact, looking at the wireshark's log, it seems like the client does not send the certificate to the server. Is that something I need to enable in the App configuration? Does the Swift CocoaMQTT package even support this feature (provide the cert to the broker)?

**EDIT:**

I tried running a client with the same cert/key with paho mqtt implemented in python, which also allows to provide the client with the CA certificate, and everything runs ok:
[image]
Trying using the same client's cert/key in CocoaMQTT implemented in iOS15 shows the MQTT broker log error message as above and the **fatal alert** shows up the the wireshark log:
[image]
Initially, I thought that the sever did not like (or did not receive) the client's certificate, but that fatal alert package destination is port 8883. So now I tend to believe that it's the client, who does not like the server's certificate. This is expected if the client uses the pool of official CAs to verify the certificate instead of recognizing that its own certificate was issued by the same CA as the server's one. This is further confirmed by setting the `allowUntrustCACertificate = true` and seems like the handshake is suspended and no more communication occurs:
[image]
There's also a debug message on the client's side:

```
Call the SSL/TLS manually validating function
```

So it looks like the client will not continue the communication until this validation process occurs. As @Brits mentioned in his comment, there's a [callback](https://github.com/emqx/CocoaMQTT/blob/12d8bc4b701714d0ed6258bba6760893df6e831c/Source/CocoaMQTT.swift#L70) to validate the cert manually but it is implemented as a part of the delegate. I do see that there's a method `mqtt.didReceiveTrust` which I assume should be used for cert validation, and I wish to use the closures approach as stated on the [README page](https://github.com/emqx/CocoaMQTT#usage) as giving an example for the `didReceiveMessage` methond:

```
Now you can use closures instead of CocoaMQTTDelegate:

mqtt.didReceiveMessage = { mqtt, message, id in
    print("Message received in topic \(message.topic) with payload \(message.string!)")           
}
```

With a weak understanding of Swift Closures, I am not able to figure out how to make that function all, so the question now becomes: how to convert that function from the delegate definition into the closure?

Comment: You are looking at a fairly old version of the example; [this](https://github.com/emqx/CocoaMQTT/blob/master/Example/Example/ViewController.swift#L168) may help. Are you sure that your server certificates is valid? (have you successfully connected to the broker using something else).

Comment: @Brits the only difference I see in your updated link is using `allowUntrustCACertificate = true`. Since both server's and client's certificates were signed by the same CA (my own created CA), why would client not trust that CA? So it does not care about it's own certificate's CA, but instead searches this CA in the pool of official CAs?

Comment: Sorry - had not read the code in detail (just noted significant change). "signed by the same CA" its quite possible (and usual!) for these to be signed by different CA's. The `allowUntrustCACertificate` setting relates to the servers certificate (and, as you say the clients cert is not being presented) I'm guessing that is your issue (I'm not sure that CocaMQTT allows you to just pass in a CA - think you need to [use this](https://github.com/emqx/CocoaMQTT/blob/master/Source/CocoaMQTT.swift#L70)).

Comment: @Brits I think you are right, but I am not using delegate, I see in my version there's a function  `didReceiveTrust`. Is there a way to set a closure for this function just like it's done for the `self.mqtt.didReceiveMessage = { mqtt, msg, id in ... }` Your answer would be greatly appreciated. Also, with this untrusted CA scenario, Apple would reject this app?

Comment: Does it work with `allowUntrustCACertificate`? I'm not sure what apple would accept but it's not too difficult to obtain a trusted certificate (e.g. Lets Encrypt & Certbot) assuming your broker is internet facing?

Comment: @Nazar, were you able to solve this? We are facing the same issue with AWS IoT Core...

Comment: @Azimuth I do not remember exactly how it worked out, but I think I was able to run some tests with the untrusted certificates option enabled. What I think is 1) this will not pass the Apple app deployment requirements and 2) Apple did not support AWS certificates. Now sure about the current policies on 1) and 2).

Comment: @Nazar, doesn't it? At least browsing to an AWS IoT Core URL in browser on an iPhone doesn't give certificate warning, so I think AmazonRootCA1 is in trusted root CA keystore in iOS.